# compressed file format for Iphone

Tags: iphone, file, compression

i am new to iPhone
i want to ask that what is the compressed file format which is supported on iPhone. Also how can extract this file programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following open source project at Google Code definitely works. I've used it in 2 apps myself:

http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

and the following discussion shows some example usage:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7615-simple-objective-c-class-zip-unzip-zip-format-files.html