# Audio File Encryption in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have recorded an audio file.what I need is I have to encrypt the audio file in Xcode programmatically,and then send it to the server.So kindly tell me how to encrypt the file.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly tell me how to do this.

Comment: Any reason not to use SSL for transport encryption rather than encrypting the file itself?

Comment: I don't know about this kindly tell me how to do this?

Comment: Set up your web server with an SSL certificate, then upload the file to the https URL. [Here's the How-To for Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html), other web servers will have similar steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the category in the answer at the link, and add this in your project and #include "CommonCryptor.h".
Get the audio as NSData, then [data AES256EncryptWithKey:key] where key is some NSString containing your password. See:
[AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Comment: when I am using the [data AES256EncryptWithKey:key]  I am getting the warnings 1.Instance method AES256EncryptWithKey: not found

Comment: See the first answer in the link. The linked code needs to be included. It adds the AES256EncryptWithKey method to NSData via a category. Lots nicer than CCCrypt().

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt your NSData using [this](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master/CommonCrypto).

Comment: In this there are so many files tell me what file I have to use

Comment: Hi Vignesh,here I want to encrypt the below image.So in ViewDidLoad I have written the NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrow_glossy_up_blue" ofType:@"png"]];

    
    NSData *encryptedData = [data1 AES256EncryptedDataUsingKey:@"srinu" error:nil];   at this line it is giving error like this. [NSConcreteData AES256EncryptedDataUsingKey:error:] unrecognized selector sent to instance .....

Comment: did you import the NSData+commonCrypto file?.

Comment: I have used this  #import "NSData+CommonCrypto.h"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9597/discussion-between-pie-and-vignesh)

Answer (score 0):

You could compress it with zlib library.

There's a wrapper called [objective-zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/) for it.

It also supports encryption.

Also take a look at accepted answer at [compressed file format for Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476459/compressed-file-format-for-iphone)

Comment: I am trying dude thanks for reply I will get back to you in few minutes